# Intersect/Diff array in PHP

Tags: php, diff, intersect

I have a problem using php like this:

Array 1: `[a=>a, b=>b, c=c, d=d]`

Array 2: `[a=>123, b=>b, c=234]`

ResultArray: `[a=>123, c=>234, d=d]`

How can I get `ResultArray` from `Array1` & `Array2`? Can anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: try array_merge

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Use `array_intersect` function  :-)

Comment: array_merge but still got b=>b in `resultArray`. Please check.

Comment: You'll have to loop and check key and value.

Comment: If a key exists in both, how to determine which value it should bear?

Comment: `$result = array_merge(array_diff($Array1, $Array2), array_diff($Array2, $Array1));`

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = ['a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b', 'c'=>'c', 'd'=>'d'];
$array2 = ['a'=>'123', 'b'=>'b', 'c'=>'234'];
$diff_array = array_diff($array1,$array2);

$final = array_map(function($d) use ($array2){
    return isset($array2[$d]) ? $array2[$d] : $d;
}, $diff_array);

print_r($final);
```